# Finding the exact amount of a sigma problem?

Tags: calculus

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)}
\end{align*}$$

This is a telescoping series; therefore I use partial fractions to solve.

$\int_{1}^{∞}  (1)/(k+1) $ = $ ((A/k)+(B)/(k+1))$

A= 1

B= -1

After solving for partial fractions I get.

$ (1/k)+(-1/k+1)$|∞

```
                 |1
```

Then I solve by subtracting

$(1/∞)-(1)/(∞+1)-(1/1+-1/1+1) = -1$

The answer is 1 yet I got -1. Some input on where I made a mistake would help.

Comment: If you're integrating, how in the workd did you get that? You should have gotten logarithms there...

Comment: $$\int_1^\infty\frac1{x(x+1)}dx=\left.\log\frac x{x+1}\right|_1^\infty=-\log\frac12=\log2$$ Anyway, how would this give you the sum of the series (and it doesn't, of course)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've made this more complicated than perhaps it needs to be. First note that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}$. Hence

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} $

$\displaystyle  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} - ... + \frac{1}{N} - \frac{1}{N+1} $

$\displaystyle  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = 1 - \frac{1}{N+1}$

Now take the limit as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : $\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}$